# Using linq select in DDD style entities

Tags: entity-framework-core, repository, domain-driven-design

Hello everyone I have question related to EF Core and DDD style entities that I have not found any proper answer about it.

Despite these two facts:
1- Repositories should return POCO entities(not DTO).
2- Domain Entities should have properties with private setter.

In my case I have to use linq select in order to choose specific column from my table so I must use linq select.

In spite of private setters, what is the best way to do this?
Should I create custom method for each custom select?

Comment: Probably [init only properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/init) may help here.

Comment: Repositories should return *domain objects*. Your EF entities can be your domain entities (but your db scheme can't diverge from you domain model).

Comment: Also, your domain objects can have public setters on their properties if this has sense business-wise.